Adding trust-ad option to systemd-networkd resolv.conf
I am currently symlinking /etc/resolv.conf to /var/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf, which automatically configures my DNS resolvers from DHCP and bypasses the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
I now need to add options trust-ad to /var/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf, but this is wiped on subsequent reboots by systemd-resolved.
I can change /etc/resolv.conf to be a static, non-symlinked file, but is there any way of getting systemd-resolved to insert options trust-ad to /var/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf when generating the file?
